# python/excel cell -> png

Tags: python, excel, png

Folks,
  There is an excel document that needs weekly updating...  Just a few cells that need to be updated, which is totally doable via: http://www.python-excel.org/

After these cells are updated, a graph is generated inside excel.  Is it possible to export this graph into a .png via python (ie, copy cells A3-B7 and export into an image)?

Thoughts, ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could export an existing chart to PNG using [COM extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). You will have to make sure the chart has been already updated with the new data before exporting.

I found this discussion of the `Charts` object helpful: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213725(v=office.11).aspx

You would up with something like this (untested code):

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xlsApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application") 
xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\TEST\WorkbookWithAChart.xlsx') 
xlsSheet = xlsWB.Sheets("Sheet 1") 
mychart = XlsSheet.Charts(1)  #'1' is the index of the chart object in the wb
mychart.Export(Filename=r'C:\TEST\MyExportedChart.png')
```

Helpful references:

- [Quick Start to Client side COM](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html)
- [Win32COM Documentation](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/docindex.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be impossible without actually using Excel.  You need Excel to draw the graph with the updated information.

If you can use Excel, you can write a macro which exports the chart to a PDF file.  Something like this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart Name").Chart.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\folder\filename.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```